# conditionally apply classname to component in react depending on window.location.href

Tags: css, reactjs

In my App component I have a navbar. This navbar is visible in all the chilren of my app component. I want to hide the navbar in one of the children. In order to achieve that I decided to use a ternary operator in order to apply a classname on the navbar component.
If the window.location.href is equal to the url of the component in which I want to hide the navbar, then a classname that hides the navbar is applied. However, my code is not working. I can still see the navbar in the component in which I want to hide it. When I inspect the document, I note that the classname that hides the navbar is not being applied. This is my code

```
<div className={window.location.href==='http://localhost:3001/checkin' 
     ?
        "navbar-hide"
      :
      
        "navbar"
      }>
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
      
      <Link to="/EventManager">EventManager</Link>
     
    </div>
```

The classname navbar is present regardless of the window.location.href.

Comment: The code is ok, what is your `window.location.href`? Either log it or check it out in a debugger.

Comment: If you are using react-router, you can use `useRouteMatch` to achieve this.